# Why is toolbar color stuck on white?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have implemented navigation drawer as mentioned in the official docs, here is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorButton</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

I've also created styles.xml in v-21 folder and aadded 'android' prefix as one other answer on a related question suggested but that didn't work either. The color of the toolbar is still white. Here is how it looks:

[image]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sampleapp.drawer">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Updated toolbar part of activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Updated Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sampleapp.drawer">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Updated styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What is the value of `colorPrimary`?

Comment: @TheWanderer Value of `colorPrimary` is #3F51B5

Comment: Try removing the `theme` field from the Toolbar.

Comment: @TheWanderer I tried removing it but toolbar still looks same.

Comment: Instead of using an `attr` for the background color, try giving it a direct color reference.

Comment: @TheWanderer How to give color to status bar in that case? As with styles, I can mention color of `colorPrimaryDark` and that applies to status bar.

Comment: Just do it as a test.

Comment: @TheWanderer Directly setting color via background attribute works.

Comment: OK. Try using `android:colorPrimary` in your style and `?android:attr/colorPrimary` in your layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180146/discussion-between-chinmay-sarupria-and-thewanderer).

Comment: @TheWanderer I already have android prefix in values-v21/styles.xml and in layout, I had already tried adding `android:` before attr, that didn't work.

Comment: Put it in your base style.

Comment: @TheWanderer Base style? If you mean normal styles.xml, I've already done that.

Comment: Can you post your manifest?

Comment: @TheWanderer Please see the updated question, I have added the manifest.

Comment: refeence AppTheme` in application android:theme

`android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: You should change theme or you can create new Style and set your color

Comment: @PouriaHemati Even after doing that, nothing changes.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria do you change it in the manifests?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Maybe by changing the color DrawerLayout ,Your problem will be resolved . set backgrand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the wrong theme for your Activity set in your Manifest.

In your `<application>` tag, change

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

and remove the `theme` field from your `<activity>` tag.

Comment: Toolbar still looks same.

Comment: Remove the `background` field from your Toolbar's XML and change `colorPrimary` to `android:colorPrimary` in your style. Remove the `v21` style.

Comment: Removed the background field, also deleted v21 folder and added android prefix in styles.xml but it still looks same.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria remove the `theme` field from your Toolbar as well.

Comment: Remove the `android:` prefixes in your style (sorry for the back and forth).

Comment: Tried that also but no effect. Do note that status bar color started showing perfectly after editing the manifest file.

Comment: Sorry again, but add back the `?attr/colorPrimary` as your Toolbar background.

Comment: Finally all dots connected and colors came back roaring, thanks a lot!